# Idle webservices connection disconnected after 5 minutes

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

I have a C# application that connects to a JAX-WS webservices endpoint hosted on an embedded tomcat server.

Something is disconnecting the client after exactly 5 minutes of inactivity and I cannot for the life of me work out what's doing it.

I've set server.tomcat.connection-timeout=-1 and server.tomcat.keepAliveTimeout=-1.

session-timeout in web.xml is set to 30 (minutes) and I've checked that the same value is being passed to HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval(int).

Nothing is written to the server logs even at TRACE level when a client connection is closed.

I can remotely debug the application server but not sure where to start digging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the client and server running locally I found the culprit - the keep-alive connection wasn't being closed by the tomcat server it was being closed by a reverse proxy.